# Counting each mousewheel scroll and outputting to a variable

Tags: jquery, scroll, blur

I'm attempting to use this jQuery [MouseWheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) plugin along with this [Canvas Image Blur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) plugin in order to have a full screen image to be either blurred or brought back into focus using the mouse scroll wheel (without actually scrolling the page).

I've been playing with this for hours but I'm having zero luck. The code I have currently is:

```
$(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
                        var o = 70;
                        if (delta > 0)
                            o = o+1;
                        else if (delta < 0)
                            o = o-1;

                        if( o != '' )
                            log( o );
                        return false; // prevent default
                    });

                function log(blurRadius) {
                    stackBlurImage( 'photosrc', 'canvas', blurRadius, false );
                };
```

I want the image to start with the blur set as 70. But this code currently only changes it to 69 or 71 depending on the scroll as it is only checking the scroll for either Up or Down. What I want it to do is output each individual scroll to the variable - similar to how in the canvas image blur example above the slider adjusts the blur dynamically.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to move the variable declaration (`var o = 70`) to outside of the function.

If the variable is declared within the event handler for mouse wheel, it is resetted each time the event occurs. If you instead declare it outside, it will be declared once the page is loaded and then just changed to +1 or -1 on each event.

You could also change `o = o + 1;` to `o++;` in order to make your code more simple.

Example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mKtvQ/2/

*(Notice: I did not include the blur code since you didn't include in the OP.)*

Comment: I knew it would be something straightforward! Thanks very much!